# Theming documentation for Gnome Shell

Tags: gnome, themes, command-line

Does anything like this exist? i started modifying the gnome-shell.css file and noticed some none w3c standard attributes in there. Anyone know where i can find some info about it?
Also is there an application/helping tool that contains gnome-shell elements (so i can see my changes easily)

Comment: Can you give some examples of the problematic CSS attributes?

Comment: Not really problematic, more like undocumented

'carret-color', '-arrow-base', '-margin-horizontal', 'background-gradient-start', background-gradient-end', etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can just suggest some reading material:

[Part III. Theming in GTK+](http://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/theming.html)

[Making GTK3 themes – Part 1: Basics](http://worldofgnome.org/making-gtk3-themes-part-1-basics/)

And links on [this page](http://funsurf-blog.blogspot.in/)

[This link](http://blog.fpmurphy.com/2011/05/more-gnome-shell-customization.html) should help?

Comment: unfortunatelly msot of the stuff you gave me refer to gtk3 theming  not GS.

Comment: @AKLP, I hope the last link I added helps. Pretty complicated stuff.